# What were the names of the medals given out in Star Wars and what was written on them?

Tags: star-wars, props

At the end of the 1977 film "Star Wars: A New Hope" Luke, Han, and Chewie are presented with  medals in front of a large crowd by Princess Leia.

What were the names of the medals?  (Medal of Valor, etc.?)  Did they have anything written in them?

Comment: I edited the question to frame it better for you. Good first question and welcome to the site.

Comment: Did Chewie actually get a medal?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

As seen in this screenshot from the end of *A New Hope* (click to enlarge it), nothing is written on the medal.

Here is a close-up graphic of the medal:

[image]

According to [Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Royal_Award_Ceremony), this medal is called the **"Medal of Bravery"**.

By the way, if you compare Han's medal to Peter Griffin's, you will find that *Family Guy* managed to make a fairly faithful version of it:

[image]